# How to send query from iOS to PHP code

Tags: mysql, objective-c

I am kinda new to Obj-C and Stack Overflow, so bear with me here (:D).  I newly found out how to send queries from PHP to the MySQL database, but I'm not really sure how to send the query from my iOS app to PHP.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: its not actually unclear but too broad for SO. we could help you with specific parts of the codebase but not everyone here will write the whole thing for you

Comment: Could you at least just lead me to a tutorial?  If not I'll just close the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't pass queries  from objective C to PHP. What we do is pass data to the server and let the server process the data and respond accordingly.

JSON is popular method to exchange data between server and a mobile device.

For example: You want to get all the fields of the database which has column `name, address , contact` of table `person`. You can't do direct database query from the device. like `SELECT * from person;`.

What we do is send HTTP request to an API like e.g `getPersonDetails.php`. 
Now it's server's responsibility to verify an authorized app is sending HTTP request to it. And after verification it will respond back the data to the application in JSON format or could be XML whatever you feel comfortable. JSON is the preferred way though.

The server response would be this in JSON format:

```
[
 {
  name:John,
  address:US,
  contact:1234
 },
 {
  name:David,
  address:UK,
  contact:1234
 }
]
```

Now after app receives this JSON object and it needs to decode the JSON into the the suitable form. 
Refer to documentation of AFNetworking here:
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking
AFNetworking is a popular library for making HTTP request to the server for Objective-C.

**Addition 1:**

**HTTP POST Request from iOS application in Objective C using AFNetworking:**

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"name": @"Andy",
                             @"address": @"UK",
                             @"contact": @"1234",};
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/addToDataBase.php" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

**Server side code to handle the POST request
http://example.com/addToDataBase.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/JSON');

$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO person VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $name, $address, $contact);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();

$result = array( "result" => "Successfully Inserted Data");
$output= json_encode($result);
echo $output;


?>
```

Comment: I see.  How 'bout if we wanted to add or remove data?  I already have the master-detail application WITHOUT the MySQL extension.  Would we put in some function, say `[self insertQuery(@"....")]`?

Comment: Thanks a ton.  I still though have 4 questions :).  1) After all this code, where does the data end up? 2) How should I create this MySQL database? 3) This AFNetworking library doesn't look like a framework.  How should I install it? 4) Is http://example.com/addToDataBase.php supposed to be http://example.com/insertdata.php?

Comment: 1) NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject); This will run once the http request will get successfully executed. The returned data will be a NSDictonary. You can check it in debugger.  2) Second question suggests that you need a lot of homework before you understand all this. Keywords are CRUD in PHP, JSON parsing in PHP, And AFNetworking in objective C. 3)There are two ways to install AFnetworking one through cocoapods and another manually dropping AFnetworking file which you can download from github. 4) Yes you are right it's supposed to be same. I have corrected.

Comment: Umm.. sorry to bother you again, but I found it really hard to install phpMyAdmin, XAMPP, ... all that stuff, so I was wondering if I could use just a simple PHP file containing JSON data like you explained ([{}, {}] form).

Comment: No there need to be a server which can respond to http requests. Learn it slowly one at a time. Dont get mind boggled by trying to take it all at once.

Comment: What is world and what is sssd?

Comment: that should be sss only. It shows the type of variable which is being bind on the query. s = string , d = decimal

Comment: So.. I have a database on some server, and I am succeeding on the addition part, but I am having trouble with the parsing part.  What PHP file should I use to send the HTTP request to?

Answer (score 0):

have IOS output something like:

```
$run_var = '$varName="variable value"';
```

then run it through eval like so

```
eval($run_var);
```

see for referencehttp://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: Eval is like a PHP universal listener for anything being submitted to it from elsewhere.

Comment: Actually, what I was trying to do was to send a query from iOS to the PHP server.  As a result, I need a form of Objective-C code.

Comment: Then your question should be something like "How to send query from iOS to Objective C code"

Comment: Not exactly.  I want to transfer the query from Objective C code to PHP.

Comment: Then run eval on the dump of the objective C query.

Comment: It's pretty easy.  The stuff inside the eval() will be passed directly to the PHP processor, so use it sparingly..

Comment: So... is there a function in Objective-C to transfer the query?  Excuse my ignorance :D.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I suspect you would load it into a PHP function through objective C.  I use PHP, not objective C, so an objective C developer can answer something like "How do I load an objective C function, so it can be passed $pass_this= (here)".